# Find the derivative of $\frac{x}{x+\frac{x}{x+\frac{x}{x+\cdots}}}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Given $f(x) = \dfrac{x}{x+\dfrac{x}{x+\dfrac{x}{x+\cdots}}}$, find $f'(x)$.

My friends and I are relatively new to calculus in general and were given this problem. We could only find how to solve this implicitly when setting up the equation like this: $f(x) = \dfrac{x}{x+f(x)}$. Is there a way to find f'(x) in terms of just x?

Comment: $f^2 + x f - x = 0$ shouldn't be too hard to solve...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$  f(x)=\frac{x}{x+f(x)}$$ $\Rightarrow $ 
$$f^2(x)+f(x)x-x=0 $$ 
$$f_1(x)=\frac{-x+\sqrt{x^2+4x}}{2} $$
$$f_2(x)=\frac{-x-\sqrt{x^2+4x}}{2} $$
$$
f'_1(x)=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{x+2}{\sqrt{x^2+4x}}-1) $$
$$ f'_2(x)=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{-x-2}{\sqrt{x^2+4x}}-1) $$

Comment: If the continued fraction converges (for a given value of $x$), it can only converge to one number, not two. So which one is it, $f_1(x)$ or $f_2(x)$?

Comment: In my opinion $$ f_1(x)   $$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use your functional equation
$$f(x)=\frac{x}{x+f(x)}$$
and derive it to find $f'(x)$ as a function of $f$ and $x$.